# is image a sample or a population

Tags: c++, image-processing, statistics

I was wondering if I take one complete gray image, then this image would act as a population or a sample? I needed to take the standard deviation of the image.
Matlab uses the standard deviation formula as that for a sample i.e. division with N-1.
I personally think that it is a population i.e. division by N is required. But then I think this image is just a sample of the actual scene which contains infinite points.

Comment: Ofcourse, total pixel number N would act as a population, it is no different than 1-D data you should divide it by N in both cases

Answer (score 1):

On a statistical note, 1/n give the minimum variance estimate (most precise), but it is biased. 1/(n-1) is the usual way to measure estimate the sample variance because it is unbiased. You know that you are calculating the sample variance because population variance can never be measured directly. We can only estimate it through the sample variance. For a nice review see this [Khan Academy Video](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/probability/descriptive-statistics/variance_std_deviation/v/review-and-intuition-why-we-divide-by-n-1-for-the-unbiased-sample-variance).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's a sample in that there are many possible images you *could* have taken, and so a much larger population of pixels. More practically, with an image, I'm guessing N is large enough so that it only makes a tiny difference what your choice of the denominator is? hth

Comment: Thanks! I thought so too. I will take it as a sample now. You are right for a larger image N or N-1 won't make a difference. But my question was part of a different problem, where images could be very small with respect of number of pixels.